# Write Unit Tests for Static Methods

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, webforms, moq, static-methods

In my project there are lots of Static methods and all are inturn hitting the DB. I am supposed to write Unit Test for the project but often struck with as all the methods are static and they are hitting DB. Is there any way to overcome this. Sorry for being abstract in the question but my concern is what is the way to write unit test for static methods and those hitting DB. MOQ is not useful when the methods are static and also in my project one method is calling other method within the same class. So in this case i cannot MOQ the inside method as both are in the same class.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to write unit tests after having written the production code. The book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://amzn.to/Vzxdhd) deals with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The project I'm currently in is lot worse than what you have described. It is a blue print of an un-testable system. There are couple of options I think, but it all depends on your situation.

Write Integration test, which hits the database, and test multiple components together. I know this is not ideal, but it at least give some confidence on the work you do. Then try to refactor your code in a small step at a time, (be sure to take baby steps) and write Unit tests around that code. Make sure your integration tests continue to pass. You are still allowed to refactor your intergeneration type tests, if the semantics are changed.

This might not be easier as I said, and it takes time. That's why I said it is depends on your situation.

Another option would be (I know many people do this with legacy code) to use one of those pricey Isolation frameworks such as Isolator, MS Fakes perhaps to fake out those un testable dependencies. Once those tests written you can look at re factoring the code to make it more testable.

Comment: Yes currently i am writing Integration Test only. I understand your solution. I'm not sure how far it will help my situation but will try to implement them.